# Radio Buttons with other option Angular

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on an Angular reactive form. The first question in the form asks what the user's favorite fruit is. I want to add an "other" option

```
<p>
            <label for="favFruit"><b>What's your favorite fruit</b></label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="Apple" id="favFruit" name="favFruit" formControlName="favFruit"> Apple
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="Banana" id="favFruit" name="favFruit" formControlName="favFruit"> Banana
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="Orange" id="favFruit" name="favFruit" formControlName="favFruit"> Orange
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="Pear" id="favFruit" name="favFruit" formControlName="favFruit"> Pear
            <br>
            <input type="radio" value="Grapes" id="favFruit" name="favFruit" formControlName="favFruit"> Grapes
            <br>
            <input type="text" value="" id="favFruit" name="favFruit" formControlName="favFruit">  
        </p>
```

What I've tried is adding in the other value as a text input field, however, this allows the user to select more than one option. I'd like for when the user clicks other for the other option to pop up so the user can select other but it will be their only selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that the `<input>` element that is used to fill in the other value not use `formControlName` directive.

When the text field is inputted, it should update the `favFruit` control value, which results in unchecking the previously checked radio button.

```
<input type="text" value="" id="favFruit" name="favFruit" #otherFavFruit 
    (input)="onOtherFavFruitInput(otherFavFruit.value)">
```

```
onOtherFavFruitInput(value: string) {
  this.form.controls.favFruit.setValue(value);
}
```

Another scenario is that when you input the text field for other value, you change your mind and select either of those radio buttons, you can use the `(change)` event to reset the input field.

```
<input type="radio" value="Apple" id="favFruit" name="favFruit" formControlName="favFruit" 
    (change)="onFavFruitChecked($event)">
```

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('otherFavFruit') otherFavFruit!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

onFavFruitChecked(event: any) {
  this.otherFavFruit.nativeElement.value = '';
}
```

Note that you can use `*ngFor` to generate a set of form controls aimed to reduce the code in HTML.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
  <input type="radio" [value]="fruit" id="favFruit" name="favFruit" formControlName="favFruit" 
      (change)="onFavFruitChecked($event)"> {{ fruit }}
  <br>
</ng-container>
```

```
fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Grapes'];
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-boh3lp?file=src%2Fmain.ts)